# getting text from selective nodes in javascript

Tags: javascript

From below HTML code I want to get all the text except that in 'text_exposed_hide' span elements.

Initially I tried to get the text from span with no class names.
But this method misses the text which is not within any span but just in div.

How can I get the required text. I need this code in pure javascript

```
<div id="id_4f1664f84649d2c59795040" class="text_exposed_root">
9jfasiklfsa
  <span>CT:PFOUXHAOfuAI07mvPC/</span>
  <span>NAg==$1ZUlmHC15dwJX8JNEzKxNDGGT</span>
  dwL/L1ubjTndn89JL+M6z
  <span class="text_exposed_hide">...</span>
  <span class="text_exposed_show">
    <span>MDmclkBPI/</span>
    <span>s4B7R9hJyU9bE7zT10xkJ8vxIpo0quQ</span>
    55
  </span>
  <span class="text_exposed_hide">
    <span class="text_exposed_link">
      <a onclick="CSS.addClass($("id_4f1664f84649d2c59795040"), "text_exposed");">See More</a>
    </span>
  </span>
</div
```

Edit :

I tried removing nodes with class name 'text_exposed_hidden' and then getting text from remaining nodes. Below is the code. But its not working
Control is not entering for loop. Even visibleDiv.removeChild(textExposedHideNodes[0]) is not working. I am running this in Chrome Browser 16.0

```
    //msg is the parent node for the div
    visibleDiv = msg.getElementsByClassName("text_exposed_root");

    textExposedHideNodes = visibleDiv.getElementsByClassName("text_exposed_hide");
    for(var n = 0;n < textExposedHideNodes.legth ; n++ ) { 
        console.log("Removing");
        msg.removeChild(textExposedHideNodes[n]);
    }

    return visibleDiv.innerText;
```

Comment: you have `n < textExposedHideNodes`, that should be `i` instead of `n` I think, also in `textExposedHideNodes[n]`

Comment: Earlier i had n everywhere. But since it was not working. I tried to replace n by i. But it does now work. I am editing the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code will collect all text from text nodes who don't have a parent with the `class="text_exposed_hide"` and put the results in an array.

It does this non-destructively without removing anything:

```
function getTextFromChildren(parent, skipClass, results) {
    var children = parent.childNodes, item;
    var re = new RegExp("\\b" + skipClass + "\\b");
    for (var i = 0, len = children.length; i < len; i++) {
        item = children[i];
        // if text node, collect its text
        if (item.nodeType == 3) {
            results.push(item.nodeValue);
        } else if (!item.className || !item.className.match(re)) {
            // if it doesn't have a className or it doesn't match
            // what we're skipping, then recurse on it to collect from it's children
            getTextFromChildren(item, skipClass, results);
        }
    }
}

var visibleDiv = document.getElementsByClassName("text_exposed_root");
var text = [];
getTextFromChildren(visibleDiv[0], "text_exposed_hide", text);
alert(text);
```

If you want all the text in one string, you can concatenate it together with:

```
text = text.join("");
```

You can see it work here: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/VynKJ/

Here's how it works:

1. Create an array to put the results in
2. Find the root that we're going to start with
3. Call `getTextFromChildren()` on that root
4. Get the children objects of that root
5. Loop through the children
6. If we find a text node, collect its text into the results array
7. If we find an element node that either doesn't have a className or who's className doesn't match the one we're ignoring, then call `getTextFromChildren()` recursively with that element as the new root to gather all text from within that element

Comment: nice; maybe finally add a `text.join('')`?

Comment: @scessor - Thanks.  I wasn't sure what the OP wanted to do with the text so I thought it was most useful leaving it in the array.  Obviously, it can be all concatenated together with `.join("")` if that's what the OP wants.

Comment: @jfriend00 Indeed the best solution. I tried it @ http://jsfiddle.net/VynKJ/7/ But it is still giving ... from <span class="text_exposed_hide">...</span>

Comment: @vaichidrewar - Where exactly do you see a problem?  I don't see an issue myself.  I modified your jsFiddle to make it a little easier to see the results here: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/xgXb2/

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
/*Get Required Text
  Desc: Return an array of the text contents of a container identified by the id param
  Params:
      id = Container DOM object id
*/
function getRequiredText(id)
{

    /*Get container, declare child var and return array*/
    var el = document.getElementById(id),
        child,
        rtn = Array();

    /*Iterate through childNodes*/
    for(var i = 0; i < el.childNodes.length; i++){

        /*Define child*/
        child = el.childNodes[i]

        /*If node isn't #text and doesn't have hidden class*/
        if(child.nodeName !="#text" && child.className != "text_exposed_hide")
            rtn.push(child.textContent);
    }

    /*Return results*/
    return rtn;
}
```

This will go through all childNodes, including nested childNodes and place all text into an array. if you want to exclude nested children replace the "if" statement with.

```
 if(child.nodeName !="#text" && child.className != "text_exposed_hide" && child.parentNode == el)
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of removing the node, why not set its innertext/html to empty string:

```
//msg is the parent node for the div
visibleDiv = msg.getElementsByClassName("text_exposed_root");

textExposedHideNodes = visibleDiv.getElementsByClassName("text_exposed_hide");
for(var i = 0;i < textExposedHideNodes.legth ; i++ ) { 
    //store to temp for later use
    textExposedHideNodes[i].txt = textExposedHideNodes[i].innerHTML;
    textExposedHideNodes[i].innerHTML = '';

}

return visibleDiv.innerText;
```